# Unity System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception Error while building WebGL project on Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've tried to build my Unity project in WebGl and it's always breaking with the Exception below. I've tried all I could for months. However, it works fine if I try to build a Mac Project instead of a WebGL project.

```
Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.SetupAndStart(ExecuteContext context, Boolean asyncMode) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Shell/Shell.cs:line 423
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.ExecuteAsync(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller, Boolean asyncMode) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Shell/Shell.cs:line 299
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Shell/Shell.cs:line 355
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/CppProgramBuilder.cs:line 334
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/ParallelFor.cs:line 78
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:129)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:65)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:811)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:778)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:604)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:276)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.CompileBuild (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:365)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:913)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:29)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:337)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
```

Comment: I'm having pretty much the same issue doing an Android Build in Linux. Any idea what is causing this? T.I.A.